# What will be the value for 'four' in enum numbers?

Tags: c, enums

I'm a newbie to C language. I found a question asking to find the value of enum numbers in C language.The exact question is written below:

*Consider the following declaration in C language*

```
enum numbers {one = 5, two = -6, three, four};
```

Please help me to find the value of '**four**' in these enum number. Also please tell me how this enum declaration works?

Comment: You can easiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiily test it.

Comment: What the code's author said by writing this is that they didn't _care_ what the value will be as long as it's unique. You shouldn't either.

Comment: @MarounMaroun Well, to be fair, even though this is trivial to test, testing alone does reveal whether the result is guaranteed to be the same every time with every compliant C compiler.

Comment: @keshlam Code does exist that relies on the "increment by one" behaviour of assigning successive `enum` values for brevity, even when the exact value does matter. That may arguably be in bad style in some cases, but in my opinion gives validity to the question.

Comment: @keshlam: Listing an identifier without a value in an enum neither means that its value will be unique nor that the author does not care about its value. The rule is that each identifier with no `=` is given a value one greater than the previous identifier, regardless of whether another already exists with the same value. This is often used to set the first identifier of a desired interval, followed by listing the remaining identifiers, as in `enum foo { ten = 10, eleven, twelve, thirteen }`.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13806093/what-will-be-the-value-of-enum-element-if-the-first-one-is-defined-to-1

Comment: Don't do this stuff it's rather pointless. Assign explicitly a value to each enum element. That way you will be sure that the values are the same on every imaginable platform. Ans it's also more clear for the programmer.

Comment: @MichaelWalz: the rules for enum values are fully specified; the values are the same on every imaginable platform.

Comment: @StephenCanon: that's correct but it's still good practice to specify all values excplicitly.

Comment: @Daman, Is this a homework question?

Comment: This question appears to be school/homework related.

Comment: The rules are clearly specified. However, I still contend that if the author didn't specify, one should take that as a hint that the values may not remain stable in future versions of the code and avoid depending upon them.

Comment: @Kevin Brown nope, this is not a homework question but I needed to understand this

Answer (score 2):

It should be `-4`. The relevant section of the C99 standard (§6.7.2.2, section 3) states that:

> **Semantics**
>
> The identifiers in an enumerator list are declared as constants that
>   have type int and may appear wherever such are permitted.109) An
>   enumerator with = defines its enumeration constant as the value of the
>   constant expression. If the first enumerator has no =, the value of
>   its enumeration constant is 0. Each subsequent enumerator with no =
>   defines its enumeration constant as the value of the constant
>   expression obtained by adding 1 to the value of the previous
>   enumeration constant. (The use of enumerators with
>   = may produce enumeration constants with values that duplicate other values in the same enumeration.) The enumerators of an enumeration are
>   also known as its members.

Quoted from ISO/IEC 9899:TC3.